# Content Search Webpart giving no results of new added documents

Tags: content-search-web-part

I uploaded couple of new documents to Document Library in Draft status. I want them to be displayed in order in Content Search query. I added the query string to search by Title but I have no results. Is it some issue when you have new documents that they are not included in search index? Do I have to reindex the library?

Answer (score 0):

Content Search WP relies on Search Service Application's incremental crawling. If you wish to speed up the process, you can manually run the incremental crawl to see whether you have configured the web part & crawling correctly.